# Foundation top-bar elements overflowing and breaking

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass

I'm using Foundation 6 with the MEAN stack. I'm using Gulp to access the sass variables. But after I set everything up, the top-bar is now overflowing and not staying inside its parent elements.

This is what it looks like:

[image: top-bar]

As you can see, both the top-bar-left and top-bar-right elements are not staying inside of their parent elements. My navigation code is almost identical to the top-bar code supplied in the Foundation documentation. Note I tried swapping out my code with the code in the Foundation site and the issue did not fix. Leading me to believe that the issue is not with the HTML:

```
<header class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
 <div class="top-bar-left">
   <ul class="menu">
     <li class="menu-text"><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home">GoodThings</a></li>
     <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="profile">Profile</a></li>
     <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="login" ng-show="!currentUser">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/logout()" ng-show="currentUser">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="button">Search</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've done next to no formatting with sass at the moment, so I have no idea why this is breaking. Any ideas????

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to recreate your issue in any way I try...

Maybe your project is missing certain SASS files for Foundation.

You could try wrapping `.top-bar-left` and `.top-bar-right` in `.row.column`to contain it?

```
<header class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <div class="row column">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else some css (margin, padding) for ul? Use developer tools to look for this kind of stuff.

[edit] Who is downvoting this comment? And why?